# Spring actuator viewer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, monitoring, metrics

Are there any applications that wrap spring actuator metrics in some nice appealing form, instead of JSON? I would like to have nice view of all existing beans, to learn how spring actualy works.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at spring-boot-admin:
https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin

Answer (score 0):

According to [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-dropwizard-metrics), `actuator` can provide data to [dropwizard](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/) metrics regestry. Dropwizard in its turn supports streaming metrics to [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) and [Graphite](http://graphiteapp.org/) backends.

Graphite can draw some charts but those look pretty plain. You can integrate it with [graphana](http://grafana.org/) dashboard to achieve impressive visualisation.